# Plotting electrical energy in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot of Energy (W) of a circuit using matlab. The equations are:

[image: Voltage]

[image: Current]

[image: Power]

[image: Energy]

[image]

plotting the voltage, current and power wasn't that hard (I think I wrote the correct code, please tell me if you think it's wrong!):

```
%Variables
t1=20e-3;t2=60e-3;N=1000;f=50;
t=linspace(t1,t2,N);
Vmax = 10; %Peak Voltage
Imax = 2; %Peak Current
f = 50; %Frequency in Hertz
omega = 2 * pi * f;
phi_default = -pi/4; %Constant for phase difference

%Equations
Vsrc = Vmax * sin(omega * t); %Equation for Voltage
Isrc = Imax * sin((omega * t) + phi_default); %Equation for Current
Psrc = Vsrc .* Isrc; %Equation for Power

%Plotting the result
figure(1); %Window 1
plot(t,Vsrc, 'b', t, Isrc, 'r', t, Psrc, 'g'); %Plotting Voltage, Current and Power
```

Now the problem is that I can't figure out a way to plot Energy in matlab. I think `Δt (Delta t)` should be defined maybe using `diff(t)` function and total energy should be something like:

[image]

And average power `Pavr` is calculated by [image] Where T is period.

So the question is, how can I plot the total instantaneous energy [image] as a function of phase difference in range [image] for this I think a `for loop` should be necessery to calculate for each phase value.

Also I want to plot the average power in the same period.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean *instantaneous* energy? And do you look for Energy **W** as function of **t** or **phi0**?

Comment: By instantaneous energy I mean W for the moment t, I am refering to a continus plot. For W I want its graph between -pi/2 and 0 so I guess it is a fucntion of phi 0. Thanks.

Comment: @Sean87 Sorry fo the edit confusion in my answer, should be correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy is calculated by integrating power over a certain period of time. As you're dealing with discrete values here, you have to approximate the integral by a sum. In your case the instantaneous energy as a function of time is

`Winst = (t2 - t1) / N * cumsum(Psrc);`

`cumsum` gives you the cumulative sum of all elements of vector `Psrc` and `(t2 - t1) / N` is the time interval.

For calculating the energy as a function of phi you have to fix the time period you'd like to consider. You calculate the energy first for given phi and then again integrate over the fixed time interval t1...t2:

```
phi = -pi/2:phi_step:0
Wphi = zeros(1, length(phi));
for k = 1:length(phi)
  Vsrc = Vmax * sin(omega * t);
  Isrc = Imax * sin((omega * t) + phi(k));
  Psrc = Vsrc .* Isrc;
  Wphi(k) = (t2 - t1) / N * sum(Psrc);
end

plot( phi, Wphi);
```

The average power is simply the mean value of `Psrc`:

`Pavg = sum(Psrc) / length(Psrc)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still cant figure out how to define `phi` and `phi0`. should it be like `phi = 0` and `phi0 = -pi/2` ?

Comment: @Sean87 I interpreted `phi` as a variable, that can have any value between `-pi/2` and 0 and is the phase difference between voltage and current. phi0 is one special value out of this range of values.

Comment: The cumsum was showing a step graph, now the Wphi only results in a single dot in plot window...I guess t is screwing it up (in omega equation). Did you got a graph with the edited code?